# R- Unsure of what to set y value equal to to create plot with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot with a facet for each region.  I added the region column at the end because I thought I could use that as the parameter for facet_wrap().

Also, what do I set y equal to if I want it to be equal to the values listed in the tibble below?

```
mydata <- 
read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/WorldPhones.csv')

names(mydata)[1] <- "year"

add_column(mydata, region = c("N.Amer", "Europe", "Asia", "S.Amer", 
"Oceania", "Africa",
                              "Mi.Amer"))

mydata
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 9
   year N.Amer Europe  Asia S.Amer Oceania Africa Mid.Amer  region
  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>    <int>   <chr>
1  1951  45939  21574  2876   1815    1646     89      555  N.Amer
2  1956  60423  29990  4708   2568    2366   1411      733  Europe
3  1957  64721  32510  5230   2695    2526   1546      773    Asia
4  1958  68484  35218  6662   2845    2691   1663      836  S.Amer
5  1959  71799  37598  6856   3000    2868   1769      911 Oceania
6  1960  76036  40341  8220   3145    3054   1905     1008  Africa
7  1961  79831  43173  9053   3338    3224   2005     1076 Mi.Amer
```

end of output

```
ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ region, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your data to long format first using `gather` from `tidyr` package for example

```
    library(tidyverse)

    mydata <- 
      read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/WorldPhones.csv')

    names(mydata)[1] <- "year"

    mydata_long <- mydata %>% gather(key = "region", value = "phones", -year)
    ggplot(mydata_long, aes(x = year, y = phones, group = region, color = region )) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~ region, ncol = 2) +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/WorldPhones.csv')

setnames(mydata, "V1", "Year")

# convert characters to type numeric
mydata <- data.table(data.matrix(mydata))

# melt to long format
mydata.long <- melt(mydata, measure.vars=colnames(mydata)[2:8], variable="Region")

# plot. Set scales to "free" to have y-axes differ between facets
ggplot(data=mydata.long, mapping=aes(x=Year, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Region, scales="free", ncol=2)
```

[image: ggplot output]